# Unable to import invoice data from .csv file

Tags: csv, odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I have some invoice data in openerp 7, exported it and tried to import it in odoo 8 through csv format.Partner_id is defined but still I am getting this error,

```
No matching record found for external id '__export__.account_account_8' in field 'Account' between rows 2 and 3
No matching record found for external id '__export__.account_journal_1' in field 'Journal' between rows 2 and 3
No matching record found for external id '__export__.res_partner_5' in field 'Partner' between rows 2 and 3
No matching record found for external id '__export__.account_invoice_line_3' in field 'Invoice Lines' between rows 2 and 3
Missing required value for the field 'Partner' (partner_id) between rows 2 and 3
IntegrityError: null value in column "partner_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While importing relational fields(let's say many2one points to 'other.table') is neccesary to import values of 'other.table' first. Otherwise you will get the errors showed.

Comment: For partner_id, I imported all customers its working. Now I am getting this error,Missing required value for the field 'account'.

Comment: the field account is required field, you need to export it too.

Comment: If I try to import accounts field, it says duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_account_code_company_uniq"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not included partner_id field and it is mandatory 
, so you need to include it in CSV file

Guideline to import from CSV [OpenERP - Importing and Exporting Data in CSV Format](http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/openerp-importing-and-exporting-data-csv-format)

Comment: I tried to import only customers but still it is giving me                         Missing required value for the field 'Customer' (partner_id) at row 2

Answer (score 0):

This is for the error:

> Missing required value for the field 'Account'

For importing invoices, besides the `Account` field at header level it also requires `Invoice Lines / Account` at the item level. Valid values for this is either `account code` or `account name`.

Answer (score 0):

Export the value that you need to import then the missing value will be gone.